# use a dataframe column value as column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I meet a problem.I has a dataframe as below:

```
                  test_index test-item test_value
Serial_Number                                 
SN_0                    1         A      A-0.1
SN_0                    1         B      B-0.1
SN_0                    2         A      A-0.2
SN_0                    2         B      B-0.2
SN_1                    3         A      A-0.3
SN_1                    3         B      B-0.3
SN_1                    4         A      A-0.4
SN_1                    4         B      B-0.4
SN_3                    5         A      A-0.5
SN_3                    5         B      B-0.5
SN_3                    6         A      A-0.6
SN_3                    6         B      B-0.6
```

I want get a dataframe like below:

```
Serial_Number       test_index             A           B              
SN_0                    1               A-0.1       B-0.1
SN_0                    2               A-0.2       B-0.2
SN_1                    3               A-0.3       B-0.3
SN_1                    4               A-0.4       B-0.4
SN_3                    5               A-0.5       B-0.5
SN_3                    6               A-0.6       B-0.6
```

i tried with `dataframe.unstack()`, `dataframe.reset_index()`,but i fail.

Comment: sorry, everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` argument, then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html). Then use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.droplevel`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) to clean-up format.

Note - I believe `droplevel` is a pandas `0.24.0` or higher method, so this will require an up to date version of pandas.

```
(df.set_index(['test_index', 'test-item'], append=True)
 .unstack(level=2)
 .reset_index(col_level=1)
 .droplevel(0, axis=1))
```

[out]

```
test-item Serial_Number  test_index      A      B
0                  SN_0           1  A-0.1  B-0.1
1                  SN_0           2  A-0.2  B-0.2
2                  SN_1           3  A-0.3  B-0.3
3                  SN_1           4  A-0.4  B-0.4
4                  SN_3           5  A-0.5  B-0.5
5                  SN_3           6  A-0.6  B-0.6
```

Comment: i like this solution. a lot..!! +1

Comment: @anky_91 appreciate that buddy :)

Comment: @user9624737 no problem buddy

Comment: @ChrisA, Do you have method to keep order of "test_item",thanks.

Comment: Hey @user9624737, do you have an example?

Comment: @ChrisA, I am so sorry for my late response.

Comment: @ChrisA  I mean keep order of "test_item" in my question example

Comment: @user9624737 sorry, not sure I understand? The order of test-item is being maintained in the above example...